# Does same scala code might produce different bytecodes?

Tags: scala, maven, md5, bytecode

I have a jar file contains scala files which I'd like to version somehow. Sometimes I can use git SHA inserted in METADATA but it's not always the case.

As a "fallback" I thought doing md5 on the bytecodes themselfs (*.class files). For that I'll need to make sure same code given to `maven package` will produce same bytecode. I found out [here](https://www.toptal.com/scala/scala-bytecode-and-the-jvm) that:

> Different versions of Scala may produce slightly different bytecode.

which is fine by me, I'm asking if there are more variables involved, mainly time as in jar creation date presented in bytecode somehow.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just using the artifact version like all maven repositories out there?

Comment: Yes, the same Scala code might produce slightly different bytecode when compiled with different Scala versions because every Scala version also includes a number of changes to the scalac compiler, which directly affects the output of the bytecode.  However, the compiler still acts in a deterministic way, so they should all be compatible in the end.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez WDYM by artifact version? jar filename doesn't include such thing neither do `MANIFEST.MF`.

Comment: @EladAharon all jars produced by a proper build tool does include such information in their name and in their associated pom, that is how all maven repositories work.